# Improve performance of google calendar import

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api

I'm working on an application that has a calendar connected to google calendar.
I created the UI from tablelayoutpanel.

The application works fine.
The only problem I have is the import sub works very slow, and 
the form is blinking for about 3 sec. 
I wanted to share with you what I have done so far, and ask you if you 
have any ideas how to make the import event more user friendly.
Hereby the import sub (located on module)

```
Public Sub GetCalENtryList(ByRef service As CalendarService, minDate As Date, maxDate As Date)

    EmptyTabelLayoutPanel1()

    Dim requeust As ListRequest = service.Events.List(service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items(0).Id) 'Entire events list

    requeust.TimeMin = minDate ' filtering between dates (mindate to maxdate)
    requeust.TimeMax = maxDate

    For Each calendarEvent As Data.Event In requeust.Execute().Items
        Try
            Dim dateSpan As TimeSpan = calendarEvent.Start.DateTime - minDate ' help me know what day of week is it
            Dim eventSpan As TimeSpan = (calendarEvent.End.DateTime - calendarEvent.Start.DateTime)  'Find out event length
            Dim pnl As myCalendarPanel = New myCalendarPanel 'item i designed that looks like panel with few labels

            With pnl
                .Name = "pnl" & index
                .lblEventSummary.Text = calendarEvent.Summary
                .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            End With
            With frmMainForm.MyCalendar1.TableLayoutPanel1
                .SetCellPosition(pnl, New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(Math.Abs(dateSpan.Days - 6), 2 * _
                                                                       (DateAndTime.Hour(calendarEvent.Start.DateTime) - 5))) 'set the pnl location on my calendar
                .SetColumnSpan(pnl, 1) 'event canoot be longer then one day
                .SetRowSpan(pnl, 2 * eventSpan.Hours) 'represent event length
                .Controls.Add(pnl) ' add pnl to tablelayoutpanel1
            End With
            index += 1
            SetlblTimeTime(pnl) 
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I could not find a solution to my issue, so I added a panel to my application that hides the calendar till import ends.

Comment: at the beginning of the sub, try adding `pnl1.SuspendLayout` and at the end of the sub, add `pnl1.ResumeLayout`